# Deprecate symfony solve

Tags: php, symfony

How to solve this problems after update symfony to ver 4.4

```
[2020-01-03 08:46:27] php.INFO: User Deprecated: The "twig.exception_listener" service is deprecated since Symfony 4.4. {"exception":"[object] (ErrorException(code: 0): User Deprecated: The \"twig.exception_listener\" service is deprecated since Symfony 4.4. at /var/www/api/var/cache/prod/Container8sfHI7P/getTwig_ExceptionListenerService.php:9)"} []
[2020-01-03 08:46:27] php.INFO: User Deprecated: The "Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\EventListener\ExceptionListener" class is deprecated since Symfony 4.4, use "ErrorListener" instead. {"exception":"[object] (ErrorException(code: 0): User Deprecated: The \"Symfony\\Component\\HttpKernel\\EventListener\\ExceptionListener\" class is deprecated since Symfony 4.4, use \"ErrorListener\" instead. at /var/www/api/vendor/symfony/http-kernel/EventListener/ExceptionListener.php:25)"} []
[2020-01-02 05:28:12] php.INFO: User Deprecated: Auto-injection of the container for "\App\Controller\InstallController" is deprecated since Symfony 4.2. Configure it as a service instead. {"exception":"[object] (ErrorException(code: 0): User Deprecated: Auto-injection of the container for \"\\App\\Controller\\InstallController\" is deprecated since Symfony 4.2. Configure it as a service instead. at /var/www/api/vendor/symfony/framework-bundle/Controller/ControllerResolver.php:64)"} []
```

Comment: Well, deprecation isn't an immediate problem for you, it only indicates that a feature will be removed at some point in the future. So you don't need to fix it right this minute, but you do need to make a plan to change your code and stop using those features in a future version of your application. At least two of those messages you've shown give you instructions about what you should use instead, so for those cases you should already have some idea of how to resolve it.

Comment: @ADyson for example second message it uses in the vendor files how can i solve it, because it vendor - not version control files.

Comment: Well, I guess that somewhere in your code you are using that "ExceptionListener" class? If so, you have to stop using it. If it's some vendor code which is using it, then you have to wait for an update from the vendor. Or you can go and check if they already issued an update. But like I said, it's only a warning...it's not actually a problem **yet**. Nothing in your code will break right now...it will only break if these classes are finally removed from the code in a future release, and you didn't make any changes to stop using them elsewhere.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I found this one tricky to solve as well. It's not automatically resolved by a composer update because it's part of the configuration that's only applied from it's [recipe](https://github.com/symfony/recipes) when you require a package for the first time.

You'll have to change three things that are also changed in the default configuration for 4.4 (I used dots below to indicate nested keys):

- in `config/packages/twig.yaml` add `twig.exception_controller: null`
- in `config/routes/dev/twig.yaml` change the `_errors.resource` to `@FrameworkBundle/Resources/config/routing/errors.xml`
- rename `config/routes/dev/twig.yaml` to `config/routes/dev/framework.yaml`